# Need design suggestions for my android application

Tags: android, service, android-activity, timer

Currently I am in process of developing my android application. My requirement is something like this.

I need to run a timer of 5mins and when timeout occurs I need to check certain things and take certain action. This need to be keep on running if the user starts the application.

In my knowledge I want to proceed like this

Create a service and start a timer in that service and do whatever needed when the timer expires. I will put one activity to interact with the service like start or stop.

I need suggestion for my approach and its pros and cons for this approach. To just run a timer do I need a service? If I run the repeated timer in a activity itself and if I press the back-button the activity will go background and will the timer also stop if I have started the timer in that activity?

I am sorry If I am not clear in my question. I have gone through the android application fundamentals and then thinking to ask this question. Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a service. You can use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and schedule a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). If the task needs to touch the UI, then you should create a Handler to which you can post a Runnable.

P.S. You asked about what happens if your activity goes to the background. The Timer will keep running unless you cancel either the task or the timer itself in `onPause` or one of the other lifecycle methods. Whichever one you do it in, you should start the timer task in the matching start-up lifecycle method. If you are not going to cancel the Timer itself, you should create it as a daemon thread.